# How will this cookie crust consistency change if overworked?

Tags: cookies, texture

My daughter is making pumpkin pie bars and the cookie crust instructions say the ingredients (listed below) need to be pulsed in the food processor until the mixture resembles coarse sand. She has ... *excessively* pulsed it, so it resembles a paste or thick batter. (Whoops.)

How will this overworking affect the texture of the crust? A crumbly shortbread is the goal, but I'm wary of what this paste will turn into!

> For the Crust:
>
> - 1 cup cold butter, cut into tiny pieces
> - 6 tbsp brown sugar
> - 3 cups flour
> - 1 egg
> - 1 tsp cold water

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I'm guessing it will still be delicious either way. :D You've already spent the ingredients. No reason not to bake it and then come back and answer your own question.

Comment: @Erica, does it flow? Maybe my answer in this other post might be helpful!
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85338/how-does-altering-the-fat-to-flour-ratio-affect-the-pastry/85345#85345

Comment: It doesn't flow, no, it's about the consistency of regular cookie dough (not shortbread). And I'll definitely be cooking it, but I'm wondering whether to put the pie filling on top (potentially making sub-par bars) or make a new cookie crust for the filling and just eat this whatever-it-is on it's own :)

Comment: My bet is that since the butter has been homogenized into the flour and the flour overworked (strengthening the gluten network) that result will be - as you already previewed - more of a pie/flan crust than a crumbly shortbread!

Comment: So how did the crust turn out?